# Fortran array name not accepted on architecture X86_64

Tags: arrays, macos, fortran

I am using a Mac and tried to compile a very simple fortran code that calculates average and standard deviation of a given sample by using gfortran compiler. The code is as follows:

```
C This is a fortran program for calculation the average, standard deviation
C and standard error of a given set of data. 
C Created by Ömer Faruk BODUR - 12 October 2014

      PROGRAM AvDevErr
      character(len=1) choise
      character(len=50) path
      real ave,x,std
      real, DIMENSION(30) :: array1
      integer h
      write(*,*)'Do you want to enter your data manually ?
     &Press "y" for yes or "n" for No then submit your choise by
     &pressing Enter:'
      read(*,*)choise
      if(choise.eq.'y') then
      sum1=0.0
      icount=0
      sum2=0.0
      write(*,*)'Please enter the values to be used when calculating
     &the average, standard deviation and standard error. When finished,
     &enter 0 then press Enter:'

      read(*,*)x

 1    if(x.ne.0) then
      sum=sum+x
      icount=icount+1
      read(*,*)x
      go to 1
      endif
        endif
      ave=sum/real(icount)

      if(choise.eq.'n') then
      sum=0.0
      icount=0
      j=1
      write(*,*)'Enter the name of your data file'
      read(*,5)path
5     format(a10)
      write(*,*)'Enter the number of data to be used in your file: '
      read(*,*)ndata
      open(10,FILE=path,status='old')
      write(*,*)'The data in your file to be used is below: '
      do 14 i=1,ndata
      read(10,7,END=99)array1(i)
      write(*,*)array1(i)
7     format(f4.2)
      sum=sum+array1(i)
      icount=icount+1
14    enddo
      ave=sum/real(ndata)
99    endif
      write(*,*)'The sum of the data is: ',sum
      write(*,*)'The number of data used is: ',ndata
      write(*,*)'the average of the data set is= ',ave

      call stdeviation(ndata,ave)
      write(*,*)'The standard deviation is: ',std
      stop
      end program AvDevErr

      subroutine stdeviation(ndata,ave)
      do 19 i=1,ndata
      sum2=sum2 + (array1(i)-ave)**2
19    enddo
      std=sqrt(sum2/real(ndata-1))
      return
      end
```

But, I get the error below which references my array name as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_array1_", referenced from:
      _stdeviation_ in ccHYprZn.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is not showing us the code for `stdeviation` which is responsible for the error.  I guess you haven't declared `array1` as an array in there (not that it would be the same variable as in this program - if this is the complete program [there's no `end`]) so the linker thinks it's a function.

Comment: very sorry about that.. I edited the code in this post by adding the subroutine stdeviation. Would you please have a look at that again?

Comment: *What the heck am i doing wrong???*  You are writing Fortran code in the 21st century without `implicit none`.  As I find myself writing repeatedly here on SO, anyone programming in Fortran without `implicit none` deserves all the pain that ensues.

Comment: I agree entirely with High Performance Mark (and additionally, would comment on fixed-form).  My guess seems correct, and `implicit none` will send you in the correct direction.  The subroutine is in a wholly different scope (is external) from the main program.

Comment: Well, you might be right, Sorry about forgetting the century I am living in, but this did not fix the problem at all.

Comment: Well you have to ensure that you insert `implicit none` into every scoping unit within your program (main program, modules, external procedures) and that you catch all undeclared entities and declare them.  Beyond that, make sure you understand the effect of `implicit none` and why I am berating you for writing code omitting it.

Comment: In addition to the `implicit none` consider using indentation, free source form, modern form of comparison operators (`==`,`/=`,...), modern form of the `do` loops and generally more spaces between the tokens in your statements.

Comment: Most Fortran compilers provide an option to impose "implicit none" even if `implicit none` is not include in a scoping unit.  I suggest using this feature to catch those times that you forget.  e.g., for gfortran, `-fimplicit-none` and for ifort `-implicitnone`.  Generalizing, while developing, use all of the warning and checking options that your compiler provides -- let the compiler do the work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `array1` to the subroutine (and `std`, too)!

```
      ! ...
      call stdeviation(array1,ndata,ave,std)
      write(*,*)'The standard deviation is: ',std
      stop
      end program AvDevErr

      subroutine stdeviation(array1,ndata,ave,std)
        real, dimension(30), intent(in) :: array1
        integer, intent(in)             :: ndata
        real, intent(in)                :: ave
        real, intent(out)               :: std
      ! ...
```

But please, do yourself a favor and convert your code to `implicit none`!

For example, the subroutine could look like:

```
      subroutine stdeviation(array1,ndata,ave,std)
        implicit none
        real, dimension(30), intent(in) :: array1
        integer, intent(in)             :: ndata
        real, intent(in)                :: ave
        real, intent(out)               :: std

        integer                         :: i
        real                            :: sum2

        ! As High Performance Mark noticed, sum2 has to be initialized first:
        sum2 = 0.

        do 19 i=1,ndata
          sum2=sum2 + (array1(i)-ave)**2
19      enddo
        std=sqrt(sum2/real(ndata-1))
        return
      end
```

Comment: I'm sure you noticed Alexander, but it's worth pointing out for the benefit of OP, that this code still contains a serious error.  When `sum2=sum2 + (array1(i)-ave)**2` is first evaluated `sum2`, on the right-hand-side, does not have an established value so any computations using it will produce junk.  Fortran does not, by default, set variables to `0` upon start up.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Well, I didn't ;-) Thanks for the hint, I added it to the answer!

Comment: Thanks guys, I completely edited the whole code with your advices. Thanks a lot.